# How can I iterate and apply a function over a single level of a DataFrame with MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks to the response to my [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11037895/24895), I now have a multi-indexed DataFrame the way that I want it.  Now that I have the data *in* the data structure, I'm trying to get it out and wonder if there is a better way to do this.  My two problems are related, but may have separate "ideal" solutions:

**Sample DataFrame (truncated)**

```
Experiment           IWWGCW         IWWGDW       
Lead Time                24     48      24     48
2010-11-27 12:00:00   0.997  0.991   0.998  0.990
2010-11-28 12:00:00   0.998  0.987   0.997  0.990
2010-11-29 12:00:00   0.997  0.992   0.997  0.992
2010-11-30 12:00:00   0.997  0.987   0.997  0.987
2010-12-01 12:00:00   0.996  0.986   0.996  0.986
```

**Iteration**

I'd like to be able to loop over this DataFrame where the iteration would take me down only 1 index dimension, i.e. an `iteritems` behavior that would return `[('IWWGCW', df['IWWGCW']), ('IWWGDW', df['IWWGDW'])]` and yield 2 DataFrames with Lead Time columns.  My brute-force solution is to use a wrapper routine that basically does `[(key, df[key] for key in df.columns.levels[0]]`.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Apply**

I'd also like to do things like "subtract the IWWGDW entries from everybody else" to compute paired differences.  I tried to do `df.apply(lambda f: f - df['IWWGDW'])` but get a `KeyError: ('IWWGDW', 'occurred at index 2010-11-26 12:00:00')` regardless of if I use `axis=1` or `axis=0`.  I've tried rebuilding a new DataFrame using the iteration workaround identified above, but I always worry when I brute-force things.  Is there a more "pandasic" way to do this sort of computation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using groupby for iteration:

```
In [25]: for exp, group in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
   ....:     print exp, group
   ....:     
IWWGCW Experiment           IWWGCW       
Lead Time                24     48
2010-11-27 12:00:00   0.997  0.991
2010-11-28 12:00:00   0.998  0.987
2010-11-29 12:00:00   0.997  0.992
2010-11-30 12:00:00   0.997  0.987
2010-12-01 12:00:00   0.996  0.986
IWWGDW Experiment           IWWGDW       
Lead Time                24     48
2010-11-27 12:00:00   0.998  0.990
2010-11-28 12:00:00   0.997  0.990
2010-11-29 12:00:00   0.997  0.992
2010-11-30 12:00:00   0.997  0.987
2010-12-01 12:00:00   0.996  0.986
```

However, I see that this doesn't drop the top level as you're looking for. Ideally you would be able to write something like:

`df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sub(df['IWWGCW'])`

and have that do the pair-wise subtraction, but because `df['IWWGCW']` drops the level, the column names don't line up. This works, though:

```
In [29]: df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sub(df['IWWGCW'].values)
Out[29]: 
Experiment           IWWGCW      IWWGDW       
Lead Time                24  48      24     48
2010-11-27 12:00:00       0   0   0.001 -0.001
2010-11-28 12:00:00       0   0  -0.001  0.003
2010-11-29 12:00:00       0   0   0.000  0.000
2010-11-30 12:00:00       0   0   0.000  0.000
2010-12-01 12:00:00       0   0   0.000  0.000
```

I'll think a bit more about this.

Comment: I ended up just coding a loop - will need to think more about this as well.

Comment: @TimWhitcomb I'm trying to do something similar here to add data to multiindexed dataframe have you had any further advancements on this?

[my use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352742/pandas-design-considerations-for-multiindexed-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but following @WesMcKinney answer, the best hack I found to drop inside the loop is just to select it right away such has:

```
for exp, group in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    print(group[exp])

Lead Time                24     48
2010-11-27 12:00:00   0.997  0.991
2010-11-28 12:00:00   0.998  0.987
2010-11-29 12:00:00   0.997  0.992
2010-11-30 12:00:00   0.997  0.987
2010-12-01 12:00:00   0.996  0.986
```

this will return a `DataFrame` of the underlying level correctly